# Ignore None field while Encoding to json with Circe for Scala

Tags: json, scala, circe

I am using scala 2.11.8 with circe 0.7.0

I am using scalajs to communicate with an API differentiating non existant field and `null` field in the sent JSON.

I am looking for a way of encoding to JSON a scala `case class` containing `Option[T]` fields that I would set to `None` to represent missing values:

```
case class Foo(
optionalFieldOne: Option[Int] = 42,
optionalFieldTwo: Option[Int] = null,
optionalFieldThree: Option[Int] = None
)

implicit FooEncoder: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo]
val test = Foo()
//What the code actually produces
test.asJson.noSpace
//>{"optionalFieldOne": 42,"optionalFieldTwo":null, "optionalFieldThree":null}

//What I would like
test.asJson.noSpace
//>{"optionalFieldOne": 42,"optionalFieldTwo":null}
```

Is there any configuration possible provided by circe? Do you have any idea how to access it, I've already looked through all release notes, github issues and their website doc without success.

In the case such configuration options are not available, how would someone implement it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Use [dropNullKeys](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/70e0fa9d778a24434610f79712e6200290dee838/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Printer.scala#L37):

> @param dropNullKeys Determines if object fields with values of null are dropped from the output.

Comment: The issue here is that I want to keep null values and only ommit fields that are set to None. Here your solution would return `{"optionalFieldOne": 42}` . The second field is missing.  I already read this solution in [link](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/585)

Answer (score 0):

Use [dropNullValues](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/585#issuecomment-344252912) as mentioned in this link:
https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/585

Answer (score 0):

```
implicit class JsonWrapper(val json: Json) {
    def removeNulls(): Json = {
      val result = json match {
        case j1 if j1.isArray =>
          j1.mapArray(_.map(_.removeNulls()))

        case j2 if j2.isObject =>
          j2.mapObject(_.removeNulls())

        case v => v
     }
     result
    }
  }

implicit class JsonObjectWrapper(val json: JsonObject) {
    def removeNulls(): JsonObject = {
      json.mapValues{
        case v if v.isObject => v.removeNulls()
        case v if v.isArray  => v.mapArray(_.map(_.removeNulls()))
        case other                => other
      }.filter(!_._2.isNull)
    }
  }
```